# SPF check failed

Tags: domains, domain-name-system, email, smtp

I am having trouble with failing to deliver mails with my setup.

Server 1 - `example.com` + Direct Admin IP: `111.111.111.111`, default domain (provided by hosting company: `vps11111.company.com`

Server 2 - `dev.example.com`, IP: `222.222.222.222`, default domain (provided by hosting company: `vps222222.company2.com`

A Jira instance runs on `dev.example.com`, I am sending an invitation email being logged in as `my.email@gmail.com` to `target.email@onet.pl`

> ```
> SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<target.email@onet.pl>:
> host mx.poczta.onet.pl [213.180.147.146]: 554 5.7.1 <target.email@onet.pl>:
> Recipient address rejected: Spf check: fail
> ```

Test

> ```
> Return-path: <my.email@gmail.com> Received: from
> dfault.return.serv2.dns ([222.222.222.222] helo=vps222222.company.com)
>    by vps11111.company.com with esmtpa (Exim 4.82)    (envelope-from
>    <my.email@gmail.com>)  id 1aILXy-00044d-K9     for
>    target.email@onet.pl; Sun, 10 Jan 2016 20:21:02 +0100
> ```

I have set the TXT record on example.com Direct Admin of `dev.example.com` to:
`"v=spf1 a mx ip4:222.222.222.222 ~all"`

`A` records for mail, smtp and pop are left to 111.111.111.111 (jira setup to use `jira@example.com` address).

`A` records for dev.example.com., ftp and www are set to 222.222.222.222.

I am confused about all this setup (my first time) and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried ending it from the domain name you own? You don't own gmail.com :)

Comment: @VirgilShelton for some reasons jira uses the admin email address as reply-to field. I'll check with email in my domain, but this does not fix the problem.

Comment: `Reply-To` should not matter. And `From` can only matter in case there is no `Sender` header. Most servers, however, only check `Envelope-From`. So If you set `Envelope-From` (and `Sender` for paranoid email servers), you can use `From` and `Reply-To` as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the email is sent with the envelope sender set to your gmail address. That means that the SPF record that is being checked is the record for gmail.com, not the one for your own domain.

You need to fix your setup so that you either use your own address as sender, or so that you send your emails through google's servers by logging in with your google account.